how to embed NotoColorEmoji.ttf when we convert html to pdf by using HtmlConverter.convertToDocument
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
fontProvider.addDirectory(getCkEditorCustomFontsPath());
PdfFont notoEmojiFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(
    "/opt/NotoColorEmoji.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
fontProvider.addFont(notoEmojiFont.getFontProgram(), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
converterProperties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

I am trying to use NotoColorEmoji but it doesn't display in PDF. I don't understand why this happens.
